# Manually add records to the result of a SQL select query via stored procedure call using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, temp-tables

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAllLocations] 

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT DISTINCT [Location] from Emp WHERE [Location] IS NOT NULL;
END
```

I need a stored procedure that will pull a result from one select query and then I need to add 2 additional results to that query. I don't want to insert the two additional results into a table I just want to "hardcode them in".

So basically if the above query has this result:

```
New York
Kansas 
California
New Mexico
```

I want to manually add Maine and Florida to that list but I don't want to add those records to the "Emp" table in that query. I'm assuming some sort of temp table might do the job but I couldn't find any solution online and I am not familiar with temp tables.

Comment: From where Maine and Florida will comes? Are you just looking for `UNION`?

Comment: It might be a union, Florida and Maine are not in the database at all and I don't want to add them.

Comment: Can I create a temp table and UNION them? If anyone can provide the code using my example I will accept their answer immediately.

Comment: select C1 from [your_table] Union Select 'Florida' Union Select 'Maine' ; this piece of code will do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union`, as in:

```
SELECT [Location] 
FROM Emp
WHERE [Location] IS NOT NULL
UNION  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
SELECT Location
FROM (VALUES ('Maine'), ('Florida')) v(Location);
```

That said, I don't see a good reason to make this a stored procedure.  You should make it either a view or a user-defined table function.  That say, the code can be used from inside a `SELECT` query.